# How do I filter UIlist items prior to displaying them?

Tags: python, interface

I am using the UIlist to create a list interface, it works well but I am puzzled about how to list data blocks with certain features or properties.

I would like to not show them in the UIlist at all. I am looking at the examples in the Ulist doc, everything looks fine but I am not sure if what I am looking for is there sine the complex example is abit too complicated for me atm.

thanks

Comment: The UIList documentation includes a fairly extensive example of how to make filters. Maybe if you give a bit more detail about exactly what you want to do I can write an example for you.

Comment: Yes it does and that was my issue, although the example is complete but it is hard to understand what and how things are filtered. I was just looking for a basic explanation for the logic.

Comment: If you post a description of a simple thing you want to achieve, I will give you an example of it.